# Is it necessary to create classes for every single database query in order to work with TableView?

Tags: java, sql, oop, javafx, tableview

In the last few days I went through some JavaFX tutorials explaining 'How to use TableViews?' Every single tutorial creates DataModel-Objects like `Person` for [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm). This is fine as long as you just want sql-statements like `select Firstname, Lastname from Person`.

But what if you don't want to create data models for every single select-query, because you join data with another objects for whatever reason? For example, `select * from Person join City join Country`. What I learned the last days is, if you create a tableview containing only `List` (representing the rows), it becomes horrible to handle formatting or even evaluating the tableview.

Is that really a javaFX thing? Or did I miss something?

#### Update

In order to make it more clear, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54083513/javafx-populating-tableview-with-models-from-different-classes). I first found this question after reading answers and comments to my question, but I am not satisfied with the answer to the linked question.

Comment: Do you have a particular use case that you're talking about?  It is typical for a UI control in an application to display the results of a particular query.   It is not common to design a UI control to display the results of some arbitrary query.

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of: [Create a dynamic tableview with generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42970625/javafx-create-a-dynamic-tableview-with-generic-types).

Answer (score 3):

Your question is mixing up two concepts here: `javafx.scene.control.TableView` on one hand, and SQL/ORM on the other hand. Let's forget about SQL queries and such as I think your concern is mostly on `TableView`.

`TableView` **must** be populated with a `List`. The inner type of this list **must** match the TableView's generic type. So for instance `TableView<Person>` will be populated with a `List<Person>`.

Other than that, the actual type of the objects representing rows can be **anything**. It *doesn't* even have to contain the data itself, or it can very-well be, for instance, a `Map<String, Object>`. In this case, you will map the keys of the row to each column by defining a `CellValueFactory` for each column, that will return the entry value for your chosen key.

Then you can convert this value to a `String` and/or a `Node`by defining a `CellFactory` for the column.

Objects with JavaFX properties can be mapped more easily, as there exists pre-made `PropertyValueFactory` that will require only the property name. But they're not the only way to go.

Example using a `Map<String, Object>` for each row:

```java
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

  private TableView<Map<String, Object>> tableView;
  private TableColumn<Map<String, Object>, String> nameCol;
  private TableColumn<Map<String, Object>, Integer> ageCol;
  
  private Stage stage;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) {
    this.stage = stage;

    //Insert a TableView into scene
    this.tableView = new TableView<>();
    this.nameCol = new TableColumn<>("Name");
    this.nameCol.setPrefWidth(250);
    ageCol = new TableColumn<>("Age");
    tableView.getColumns().add(nameCol);
    tableView.getColumns().add(ageCol);
    
    nameCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
      Map<String, Object> v = param.getValue();
      return new SimpleStringProperty(v == null ? null : (String) v.get("name"));
    });
    
    ageCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
      Map<String, Object> v = param.getValue();
      return new SimpleObjectProperty<Integer>(v == null ? null : (Integer) v.get("age"));
    });
    ageCol.setCellFactory(param -> {
      return new TableCell<>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
          if (empty || item == null)
            super.setText("");
          else
            super.setText(NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(item));
          //Could also call setGraphic(Node)
        }
      };
    });
    
    final Scene scene = new Scene(new BorderPane(tableView), 640, 480);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setOnShown(event -> stageReady()); //Continue when stage is rendered
    stage.show();
  }

  private void stageReady() {
    //Generate data
    List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> obj1 = new HashMap<>();
    obj1.put("name", "Name of Object 1");
    obj1.put("age", 42);
    data.add(obj1);
    Map<String, Object> obj2 = new HashMap<>();
    obj2.put("name", "OBJECT 2");
    obj2.put("age", 53);
    data.add(obj2);
    //Show data
    tableView.getItems().setAll(data);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
  }

}
```

`ageCol.setCellFactory` is only here for demonstration. If I had not set it, then the `Integer` cells would have been rendered calling `Integer.toString()` for the cells `text` property.

Comment: Yeah correct. SQL is not the problem... Maybe my example wasn't well chosen.
So the most common way is to use Collections(e.g. Map) to handle such mixed Entitys? Can I still use bindings with maps? For example I want to style the tableview depending on its cell content

Comment: Collections, JsonObjects from json-simple, anything

Comment: You can use bindings, but without JavaFX properties, they won't react to changes in your data objects. You can also use the `TableCell` produced by `CellFactory` to update styles in its `updateItem` method

Comment: Your `TableView` also has a row factory that works in a similar way as a cell factory. I could go on all day long. If you want more guidance, ask a specific question.

Answer (score 3):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33713663/230513), a database query can be used to construct an `ObservableList<Map>` of attribute-value pairs. As shown in [*Adding Maps of Data to the Table*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm#sthref117), [`MapValueFactory`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/MapValueFactory.html#MapValueFactory%28java.lang.Object%29) is "A convenience implementation of the `Callback` interface," like `PropertyValueFactory`, "designed specifically for use within the `TableColumn`. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72437983/230513), the convenience comes at a cost.

Inspired by this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513), the variation below displays a `TableView` containing the entries contained in the `Map<String,​String>` returned by `System.getenv()`. Although that map is unmodifiable, simple editing support is shown.

[image]

```
import java.util.Map;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/18620705/230513
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781121/230513
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/9134371/230513
 */
public class TableMapSample extends Application {

    private final String columnKey = "Key";
    private final String columnValue = "Value";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<Map.Entry<String, String>> list
            = FXCollections.observableArrayList(System.getenv().entrySet());
        TableView<Map.Entry<String, String>> table = new TableView<>(list);
        table.setEditable(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> keyColumn = new TableColumn<>(columnKey);
        keyColumn.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> p)
            -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getKey()));
        table.getColumns().add(keyColumn);
        keyColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

        TableColumn<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> valueColumn = new TableColumn<>(columnValue);
        valueColumn.setCellValueFactory((TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Map.Entry<String, String>, String> p)
            -> new SimpleStringProperty(p.getValue().getValue()));
        valueColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        valueColumn.setPrefWidth(800);
        table.getColumns().add(valueColumn);

        stage.setTitle("Table Map.Entry<K,V>");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(table)));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [_Why should I avoid using PropertyValueFactory in JavaFX?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72437983/230513).