# JavaFX - How do you use MapValueFactory in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, javafx

I am trying to use MapValueFactory on a TableView in Kotlin. I found a good example in Java at https://jenkov.com/tutorials/javafx/tableview.html

The following Java code works fine:

```
package com.example.tableview;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.MapValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

        var tableView = new TableView();

        TableColumn<Map, String> firstNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("firstName");
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory<>("firstName"));

        TableColumn<Map, String> lastNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("lastName");
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new MapValueFactory<>("lastName"));

        tableView.getColumns().add(firstNameColumn);
        tableView.getColumns().add(lastNameColumn);

        ObservableList<Map<String, Object>> items = FXCollections.<Map<String, Object>>observableArrayList();

        Map<String, Object> item1 = new HashMap<>();
        item1.put("firstName", "Randall");
        item1.put("lastName" , "Kovic");

        items.add(item1);

        Map<String, Object> item2 = new HashMap<>();
        item2.put("firstName", "Irmelin");
        item2.put("lastName" , "Satoshi");

        items.add(item2);

        tableView.getItems().addAll(items);
        Scene scene = new Scene(tableView, 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

When I cut and paste that code into a Kotlin project in IntelliJ, it attempts to auto-translate from Java to Kotlin. However, the generated code won't compile.  It says there is a Type Mismatch trying to add firstNameColumn to tableView.columns.

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Nothing!
Found: TableColumn<Map<*, *>, String>
```

Here is the generated Kotlin code that DOES NOT compile:

```
package com.example.tableview

import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.collections.FXCollections
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn
import javafx.scene.control.TableView
import javafx.scene.control.cell.MapValueFactory
import javafx.stage.Stage

class HelloApplication : Application() {

    override fun start(stage: Stage) {

        val tableView: TableView<*> = TableView<Any?>()

        val firstNameColumn = TableColumn<Map<*, *>, String>("firstName")
        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(MapValueFactory("firstName"))

        val lastNameColumn = TableColumn<Map<*, *>, String>("lastName")
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(MapValueFactory("lastName"))

        tableView.columns.add(firstNameColumn)
        tableView.columns.add(lastNameColumn)

        val items = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Map<String, Any>>()

        val item1: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        item1["firstName"] = "Randall"
        item1["lastName"] = "Kovic"

        items.add(item1)

        val item2: MutableMap<String, Any> = HashMap()
        item2["firstName"] = "Irmelin"
        item2["lastName"] = "Satoshi"

        items.add(item2)

        tableView.items.addAll(items)
        val scene = Scene(tableView, 320.0, 240.0)
        stage.title = "Hello!"
        stage.scene = scene
        stage.show()

    }

    fun main() {
        Application.launch(HelloApplication::class.java)
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I have gone down several rat holes on this trying to get Types correct...

Comment: The value factory classes are pretty much defunct since the advent of lambda expressions in Java 8. In modern Java you would do something like `firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().get("firstName")));`, though you would have to fix the types first. (Should be `Map<String, String>`, `TableView<Map<String, String>>`, and `TableColumn<Map<String, String>, String>`). I don't know kotlin, but I would at least recommend starting from trying to translate Java that is more recent than 2014.

Comment: Changing your table view initialization to `val tableView: TableView<Map<*, *>> = TableView()` should make it compile in Kotlin. Could be shortened to `val tableView = TableView<Map<*, *>>()`.

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781121/230513) illustrates lambdas as an alternative to `MapValueFactory`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Compiler Error

Your compiler error comes from the fact you made `tableView` a `TableView<*>`. It doesn't know enough about the types to allow you to add anything to the columns list. Simply changing this line:

```kotlin
val tableView: TableView<*> = TableView<Any?>()
```

To one of the following:

```kotlin
val tableView: TableView<Map<*, *>> = TableView()
// or
val tableView = TableView<Map<*, *>>()
```

Will let your Kotlin code compile, and run as expected.

### Problem With Your Java Code

Your Java code compiles because there you made `tableView` the raw type `TableView`. That means no generics associated with the `TableView` are used. You should never use raw types unless you're interacting with legacy code older than Java 5.

You should change:

```java
var tableView = new TableView();
```

To:

```java
var tableView = new TableView<Map<?, ?>>();
```

Note you're also using raw types when parameterizing the `TableColumn`s. The fix is similar, but unfortunately it breaks the ability to use `MapValueFactory` due to the fact it declares a raw type when it implements `Callback`. The real fix is to not use `MapValueFactory` (see below).

---

## Don't Use `*ValueFactory` Classes

Classes such as `PropertyValueFactory` and `MapValueFactory` were added at a time when lambda expressions (in Java) were not a thing. That meant using an anonymous class. Anonymous classes can be pretty verbose, so they added convenience classes to make the code easier for developers. But they have two disadvantages: they rely on reflection and, more importantly, you lose all compile-time validations (e.g., whether the property exists, the type of the property, etc.).

In both Java and Kotlin, I would recommend using lambda expressions (while also never using raw types).

Java:

```java
// Note everywhere is using a Map<String, String> now
var tableView = new TableView<Map<String, String>>();

TableColumn<Map<String, String>, String> firstNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("firstName");
firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue().get("firstName")));

TableColumn<Map<String, String>, String> lastNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("lastName");
lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue().get("lastName")));
```

Kotlin:

```kotlin
// Again, note everywhere is using Map<String, String>
val tableView = TableView<Map<String, String>>()

val firstNameColumn = TableColumn<Map<String, String>, String>("firstName")
firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory { SimpleStringProperty(it.value["firstName"]) }

val lastNameColumn = TableColumn<Map<String, String>, String>("lastName")
lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory { SimpleStringProperty(it.value["lastName"]) }
```

Although I made everything use `Map<String, String>` in both versions, you can obviously parameterize the `Map` differently to fit your needs.

Comment: I recall trying to use MapValueFactory with Java pre-lambda, and, even though it worked then it was horrible to use and the application of generics involved was super-confusing.  Not using the MapValueFactory at all and using lambdas instead is so much better . . .

Comment: Wow. Can't thank you enough for this answer. Incredibly clear, thorough, and effective. Very much appreciated!