# JavaFX MapProperty behave like an array

Tags: java, javafx

Not sure the topic makes 100% sense, it was the best I could come up with, but this is want I want:

I have a normal, fix sized, byte array like this:

```
private final byte[] dmxDataArray = new byte[512];
```

Working fine, I can put data into the array like this:

```
dmxDataArray[channel] = (byte) value;
```

I'm using the array in a JavaFX app and I want to show the array data in the GUI so I want to turn the array into a MapProperty so I can attach addListener and update the GUI when new data are added to the Map. I need to use a Map since I need to have a key-value, or any other option accessing the data using some sort of index.

This is what I have tried (using Integers instead of byte, which is fine):

```
MapProperty<Integer, Integer> dmxDataArrayProperty dmxDataArrayProperty = new SimpleMapProperty<>(FXCollections.observableHashMap());

public final SimpleMapProperty<Integer, Integer> getDmxDataArrayProperty() {

  return (SimpleMapProperty<Integer, Integer>) dmxDataArrayProperty.get();

}

public final void setDmxDataArrayProperty(Integer value, Integer channel) {

  dmxDataArrayProperty.put(value, channel);

}

public final SimpleMapProperty<Integer, Integer> dmxDataArrayPropertyProperty() {

  return (SimpleMapProperty<Integer, Integer>) dmxDataArrayProperty;

}
```

Is that what you would do? Not sure about the getDmxDataArrayProperty and dmxDataArrayPropertyProperty, why do I need to cast to (SimpleMapProperty<Integer, Integer>)?

Above is working, I can put data into the Map like this:

```
setDmxDataArrayProperty(channel, value);
```

And I can attach a listener like this:

```
dmxDataArrayPropertyProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {

  //Do something

})
```

I have worked with BooleanProperty, StringProperty and IntergerProperty before but I find MapProperty a litte bit more tricky.

Also, I not sure how to get the MapProperty elsewhere in my code, I would think that I should use getDmxDataArrayProperty() but that is giving me this:

```
class com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableMapWrapper cannot be cast to class javafx.beans.property.SimpleMapProperty
```

Also, can I(should I?) use a ObservableArray instead?

I would like the possibility to print/show all 512 (0 as initial value) values when changes are made and also the option to get just one specific value (based on the key)

Comment: *"any other option accessing the data using some sort of index."* If the keys are just integers, in order, why not simply use a list? Or `ObservableIntegerArray`?

Comment: Maybe that is the solution. I just don't know how. This is new terrain for me :/

Comment: It's not really clear what the question is. As for the cast, why not just make the return type of the method `MapProperty<Integer, Integer>` (or the equivalent for whatever data structure you decide to use), and omit the cast? Why do you need to return a specific implementation type?

Comment: Changing the return type wont work for getDmxDataArrayProperty. Sorry. I know this is not as clear as it could be, I find I hard to fine any tutorials/howto concerning this part of JavaFX. Maybe it is even more unclear, but maybe I should ask "how can I turn my dmxDataArray array into a property?

Comment: I think instead of “into a property” you just mean “into something observable” no? You just want to respond to changes, so all you need is observability. `ObservableList`, `ObservableMap`, and `ObservableSet` are the direct observable counterparts of the standard Java interfaces `List`, `Map`, and `Set`, respectively

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. Sorry for the confusing.

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69781121/230513) displays an existing `Map` in a `TableView`.

Comment: "_Changing the return type wont work for getDmxDataArrayProperty_" – Can you explain this? [`SimpleMapProperty`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/SimpleMapProperty.html) does not expose any specific public API that [`MapProperty`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.base/javafx/beans/property/MapProperty.html) does not. The former is simply a concrete implementation of the latter. But if you must return `SimpleMapProperty`, then to avoid the cast you just have to change the field type from `MapProperty` to `SimpleMapProperty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like all you need is "observability" (i.e. the opportunity to respond to changes in the data structure). The JavaFX interfaces `ObservableList`, `ObservableMap`, and `ObservableSet` are the direct *observable* equivalents of the standard `java.util` collections interfaces `List`, `Map`, and `Set`, respectively. So I think all you need here is an `ObservableList` (`List` being the collection interface which most closely mimics an array).

You can do something like:

```
public class Model {

    private final ObservableList<Byte> bytes ;

    public Model(byte[] bytes) {
        this.bytes = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        for (byte b : bytes) this.bytes.add(b();
    }

    public void setByte(int index, byte b) {
        bytes.set(index, b);
    }

    public void getByte(int index) {
        return bytes.get(index);
    }

    public ObservableList<Byte> getBytes() {
        // prevent things like getBytes().add() etc.
        return FXCollections.unmodifiableObservableList(bytes);
    }

    public byte[] getBytesAsArray() {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[bytes.size()];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < bytes.size(); i++) {
            byteArray[i] = bytes.get(i);
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
}
```

and then

```
myModel.getBytes().addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<Byte> change) -> {
   // ...
});
```

See the [`ListChangeListener.Change` documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) for more information.

The exact API in the `Model` class may need to be modified for whatever your actual use case is.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still a bit unsure about this, think you got it right, unsure about how to implement it. Doing this:  private final byte[] dmxDataArray = new byte[512]; &     Model dmxDataArrayObservable = new Model(dmxDataArray); and are adding data like this:  dmxDataArrayObservable.setByte(channel, (byte) value); but are getting this: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "perm" because "<parameter1>" is null & java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0

Comment: @droid Those are pretty standard types of error to debug, but fairly obviously I don't have enough information to do so here. Not sure exactly what `perm` and `<parameter1>` refer to, but they should be pretty obvious from the context of the stack trace. Similarly for the index out of bounds exception.

Comment: Ok. So my approach Model dmxDataArrayObservable = new Model(dmxDataArray) is correct?

Comment: @droid Yes, basically. I had intended the `Model` class to be a general model in the MVC sense, having other properties etc for the application, so the variable name doesn't make much sense in that context. But obviously, since the constructor takes a `byte[]` parameter, that's what you need to pass in.

Comment: Thanks. I am very new to Java/JavaFX and I really want to understand, I'm not here just to get it working, I want to understand it. I find it fairly complex making a entire new class, I thought something like that (ObservableList) was built into JavaFX?

Comment: @droid `ObservableList` is built in to JavaFX. I am using the built-in class (actually an interface) in the code I posted. Defining new classes is a very frequent task in Java programming, though. There is nothing complex or unusual about it. If you are new to Java, though, you might consider just learning the basics before you dive into a moderately complex framework/library such as JavaFX.

Comment: Ok that was maybe not the correct word choice. I dont find Java or JavaFX too complex in that sense. My App uses tons of self-defined classes, I very much like this aspect. I just thought that there was a more simply way when considering how simple it is to use for example the IntegerProperty (heavily using that already). I will dive more into your example and maybe be back. Thanks.

Comment: @droid I think you were misunderstanding the context for the code example. I just called it `Model` to indicate you would put the `ObservableList` in the same place as the other data (e.g. the `IntegerProperty`, etc), i.e. in the data model for your application. Using the `ObservableList` is no more difficult than using an `IntegerProperty` in principle (though implementing change listeners is perhaps slightly more tricky).

Comment: Thanks. I think it is working now. Dont know why I got the errors before :/ And yes, there might be a "small" language barrier here, I'm not using English that often. And you are right, the change listeners looks bit more complex than normal addListener :-)

Comment: I have accepted your answer as that is a very fine solution to what I was looking for, thank your for that. I have found out that the errors I was referring to was properly to do with some performance-issues. In my app I need to update the list, very, very often and that have been no problem with the array I have used so far. If I lower the update rate in my app then there is no problem with the ObservableList. I think I will generate a new topic with a more detailed example, is that the right approach?

Comment: @droid Yes, create a new question for that.