# Displaying a Hashmap in a TableView in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

I wan to display the hashmap in a table view but an error is raised and it tells me that it can't access the 'key' and 'value' (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya2HJ.png)

i have an error message that says it doesn't recognize 'key' and 'value', here is the error

```
WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'key' in PropertyValueFactory: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@46e7f3a2 with provided class type: class java.util.HashMap$Node
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline cannot access a member of class java.util.HashMap$Node (in module java.base) with modifiers "public final"
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.PropertyReference.get(PropertyReference.java:176)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.getCellDataReflectively(PropertyValueFactory.java:184)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:154)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:133)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:593)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:646)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:469)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:120)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:539)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.<init>(TableRowSkinBase.java:159)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:213)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:897)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9540)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9627)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1749)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1726)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1852)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2755)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1245)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1206)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:576)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2482)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:412)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:438)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:563)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:543)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:536)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:342)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline cannot access a member of class java.util.HashMap$Node (in module java.base) with modifiers "public final"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:560)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.PropertyReference.get(PropertyReference.java:174)
    ... 45 more

Mar 29, 2024 11:37:40 AM javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory getCellDataReflectively
WARNING: Can not retrieve property 'value' in PropertyValueFactory: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory@58cfdf9c with provided class type: class java.util.HashMap$Node
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline cannot access a member of class java.util.HashMap$Node (in module java.base) with modifiers "public final"
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.PropertyReference.get(PropertyReference.java:176)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.getCellDataReflectively(PropertyValueFactory.java:184)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:154)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory.call(PropertyValueFactory.java:133)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:593)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.getCellObservableValue(TableColumn.java:578)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:646)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:469)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:120)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:539)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.<init>(TableRowSkinBase.java:159)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:213)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control.doProcessCSS(Control.java:897)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Control$1.doProcessCSS(Control.java:89)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper.processCSSImpl(ControlHelper.java:67)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper.processCSS(NodeHelper.java:145)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9540)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9627)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1749)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1726)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1852)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2755)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1245)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1206)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1213)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:576)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2482)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$2(Toolkit.java:412)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:438)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:563)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:543)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulseFromQueue(QuantumToolkit.java:536)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$11(QuantumToolkit.java:342)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline cannot access a member of class java.util.HashMap$Node (in module java.base) with modifiers "public final"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:392)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:674)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:560)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.property.PropertyReference.get(PropertyReference.java:174)
    ... 45 more
```

Comment: Format the stack traces as code to make them readable. You probably need to create and post a [mre] for this question to be answerable.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72437983/why-should-i-avoid-using-propertyvaluefactory-in-javafx-and-what-should-i-use-i

Comment: Complete examples of displaying a `Map` in a `TableView` may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67586930/230513).

Comment: Actually, this really is a duplicate of the question referenced above. Specifically note: "Reflection also requires opening packages to loosen security in a modular application, otherwise you will receive error messages such as this". This is the problem you're encountering here, and you have no reasonable fix for it (because you can't open `java.util` from the `java.base` module to `javafx.base`). Just create the cell value factories using lambda expressions instead of using the legacy `PropertyValueFactory` class.

Comment: My code here: https://replit.com/@abramia/KeyValue?v=1